# Use IRR function with discontinuous cells in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to use a range of cells that are not next to each other with the IRR function?

I'd like to use IRR this way:
 =IRR(A1:A3 AND B2) meaning read A1, A2, A3, B2 the same way you would read A1:A4

is that possible?

Comment: I played with it and don't see a way to make your method work.  That said you can always use simple formulas such =a1, =a2, =a3, =b2 to put all your reference on a single line somewhere else on the page.  If you want to cover the intermediary cells then use white out... that is white text on a white cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define a "name range" to do that.

[image]
Select A1:A3, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on B2.  In the field (with red circle) type a name like `myrange` (you make it up!) and press enter.  Then `myrange` is defined as A1:A3,B2.

Now your formula becomes `=IRR(myrange)`.

If you want to add/remove/edit `myrange` click "Name Manager" (blue circle).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to write all the cells of the range inside another parenthesis and separate them with commas.

The solution is quite simple in terms of your example:
So change

```
IRR(A1:A3 AND B2)
```

to

```
IRR((A1:A3,B2))
```

Here is a simple example:

[image: Here is a simple example]